# Vertically align 2 divs in responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I've got 2 cards that stack in portrait but are next to each other in landscape. I'd like to have the 2 cards vertically aligned to each other in landscape. i.e. The text of the first card should be aligned to the middle of the image. I tried the flex option but that breaks in the responsive design. Little help. Thanks.

```
<div class="land6">
    <header>
        <h4>T++++</h4>
    </header>
    <div>
        <p>ipsom lorem</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="land6">
    <div>
        <img class="right" src="/Thumbs.jpg" width="100%" />                   
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
    .land6{width:49%}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use flex-boxes then you will need another approach:

```css
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  
  .land6 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) {

  .wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .land6 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
  }
}



.land6 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  
  <div class="land6">
    <header>
        <h4>Some header</h4>
    </header>
    <div>
        <p>ipsom lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="land6">
    <div>
      <img class="right" src="http://www.wfn360.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/thumb.jpeg" />                   
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Ah, valign in the landscape css. Thanks. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @user5753132 You could accept this answer if it fits your needs. :)

Answer (score -1):

If your style didn't change when you move from portrait to landscape so you don't need to put the media query here.

To make each card stack on each other, make it take full width of their parents by example: `width:100%` so it won't let the other cards stay next.

To make the text in the middle of the image, if you already stack it on each other, simply use `text-align:center` will solve the problem